# How to determine iOS device has cellular capability to start significant-change location service or not?

Tags: ios

How to check whether iOS device has a cellular capability to start significant-change location service?

Arcording to my knowledge, significant-change location service using cellular tower to locate your device location. So I would like to check cellular capability on my device before start/don't start significant-change location service.

I also google, I found Reachability, but may be Reachability only detect current active connection.

Any advice was appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
 [UIDevice- extension](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension)

Comment: I read the example, and try to determine cellular capability below:
[[UIDevice currentDevice] forceWWAN];
but I got a value TRUE even though I turn off cellular in iOS device. Can you help me?